# Remote Login With Curl

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I making a bot for remote server login system.For this,I coding something,

**sample.php**

```
<?php
$EMAIL      = "***";
$PASSWORD   = "***";
function cURL($url, $header=NULL, $cookie, $p=NULL)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    if ($p) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $p);
    }
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result) {
        return $result;
    } else {
        return curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}
$a = cURL("http://forum.donanimhaber.com/login2.asp",true,null,"Login=$EMAIL&password=$PASSWORD");
preg_match('%Set-Cookie: ([^;]+);%',$a,$b);
$c = cURL("http://forum.donanimhaber.com/login2.asp",true,$b[1],"Login=$EMAIL&password=$PASSWORD");
preg_match_all('%Set-Cookie: ([^;]+);%',$c,$d);
for($i=0;$i<count($d[0]);$i++)
    $cookie.=$d[1][$i].";";
echo cURL("forum.donanimhaber.com",null,$cookie,null);
?>
```

I use this code www.myhost.com/sample.php...Login is successfull.But I am not redirecting forum.donanimhaber.com...In forum.donanimhaber.com,When I click on any link my browser redirect myhost.com/link.php and appear empty page.Normally required to be forum.donanimhaber.com/link.php...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code shall generate the exact HTML of the page and output it. All the links in the that page will be relative links. Like, `<a href="/page.php>...</a>`. SO when you click you are actually getting redirected to `mysite.com/page.php`. And as it might be your settings, you are getting 404 not found and a blank page.

To overcome this you should either replace all the links to redirect to forum. Or use `.htaccess` toforce redrect all links except your main page.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://forum.xyz.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# do not do any rewriting to this file
RewriteRule index\.php$ - [L]
```